# H2 Database Engine version upgrade from 1.4.182 to 2.0.X fails with Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision ("2147483647")

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2

13:36:33     [2022-01-13 00:07:02,019] [INFO] [Test worker] [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory] [reqid=] - Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
13:36:33     [2022-01-13 00:07:02,092] [INFO] [Test worker] [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] [reqid=] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
13:36:33     [2022-01-13 00:07:02,100] [INFO] [Test worker] [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] [reqid=] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
13:36:33     [2022-01-13 00:07:02,421] [WARN] [Test worker] [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl] [reqid=] - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table converted_object (converted_objects_entity_ent_id varchar(22) not null, converted_objects varchar(2147483647))" via JDBC Statement
13:36:33     org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table converted_object (converted_objects_entity_ent_id varchar(22) not null, converted_objects varchar(2147483647))" via JDBC Statement
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) [spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) [spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) [spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) [spring-boot-test-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) [junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
13:36:33        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106) [gradle-testing-jvm-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58) [gradle-testing-jvm-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38) [gradle-testing-jvm-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66) [gradle-testing-jvm-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51) [gradle-testing-base-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source) [?:?]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117) [gradle-testing-base-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404) [gradle-messaging-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63) [gradle-base-services-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46) [gradle-base-services-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55) [gradle-base-services-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2]
13:36:33        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_302]
13:36:33     Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1048576" inclusive; SQL statement:
13:36:33     create table converted_object (converted_objects_entity_ent_id varchar(22) not null, converted_objects varchar(2147483647)) [90150-202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.getInvalidPrecisionException(Parser.java:7335) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfDataType1(Parser.java:7294) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfDataType(Parser.java:7107) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:7089) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:6964) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseTableColumnDefinition(Parser.java:10398) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:10336) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:7803) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:1140) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:1068) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:1037) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:965) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:614) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:552) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1111) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
13:36:33        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
13:36:33        ... 83 more

Comment: Please provide information about what actually triggers that exception. Are you loading or persisting something? What are you persisting? Is it bound to a field of a specific type?

Comment: Hi @JensSchauder,

I have found the below actual root cause of the issue... Basically while initializing the H2  embedded DB it fails to create the table with defined precision...

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1048576" inclusive; SQL statement:
13:36:33     create table converted_object (converted_objects_entity_ent_id varchar(22) not null, converted_objects varchar(2147483647))

Comment: @JensSchauder, I have updated the error log... 
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table converted_object (converted_objects_entity_ent_id varchar(22) not null, converted_objects varchar(2147483647))" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1048576" inclusive; SQL statement:
13:36:33     create table converted_object (converted_objects_entity_ent_id varchar(22) not null, converted_objects varchar(2147483647)) [90150-202]

This is the main error. Please help

Comment: This problem should be fixed with version 2.1.212. See https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3457 respectively https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/3464. They allowed only a max length of 1024 * 1024 (1048576) vor var* types in the past.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem. The cause is that H2 is mapping the Hibernate column type "text" to varchar(2147483647) just to complain about this precision later. It seems buggy to me.

In my case I only have one table with a problem. As a workaround I created it explicitly with a create statement where I used varchar(4000) instead of varchar(2147483647). That's enough for testing purposes.
The error from the automated creation is still coming but it is ignored.

My colleague is trying to override the H2 dialect as a long term solution.